# jQuery ajax post request not sending data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am sending post request to my php code using jQuery ajax, but it's not sending data.

```
var uploadData = {
    'email': email
};
$.ajax({
  url: './upload.php',
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: uploadData,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    return(true);
  },
  error: function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    return(false);
  }
});
```

I tried to add `dataType:'json',` and `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` tried to change post to get, but nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: no need to `JSON.stringify`

Comment: try with var formData = {'email':"test@gmail.com"}; and pass this formdata

Comment: You can see from the console that the request clearly has data (regardless of the use of `JSON.stringify` or not). How are you determining there is no data being sent? What is the server side code that receives this request?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan removing `JSON.stringify` not changes anything. My php code is simple now: `echo json_encode($_POST['email']);` and it returns null

Comment: My point was, how do you know it returns nothing? Your JS code is doing nothing with the response. Try adding a `success` or `error` handler function.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have `success` and `error` functions, i omitted them here to simplify my code

Comment: @Rp9 not working

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i edited original post, please check it out. Is there something else i can do with it?

Comment: What does `console.log(xhr.responseText)` show? You could also try `console.log(data)`. Also note that both `return` statements are redundant as the request is asynchronous

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164747/discussion-between-randomsuffer-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: './upload.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    'email': 'test@gmail.com'
  },
  success: function(data) {
    return data;
  }
});
```

That code works for me.

Comment: Why `return` on success function?

Comment: `echo $_POST['email'];` returnes indefined

Comment: oh sorry, i jsut test it for my php file to return the data from my php file

Answer (score 1):

For future googlers, If you have been trying to send an array via `post`,and had initialised your array as

```
var blah = [];
```

Try making it an object as below, and see if it works.

```
var blah = {};
```

Comment: I was baffled why it wasnt posting data and it turns out I made the same mistake. Upon realizing i wanted to post the same for future googlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pure request payload using:

`$raw =  file_get_contents('php://input');`

then you can decode it from json to array:

`$data = json_decode($raw, true);`

and print the array:

`print_r($data);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need for JSON.stringify.

In $.ajax call, configurain object's member "method" is used if the jquery version is >= 1.9.0 and "type" is used for the older versions. ( http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ) Here is a snippet :

```
$.ajax({
    url: './upload.php',
    method: "POST", //**'type' if jquery v < 1.9.0 **
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        email: "test@gmail.com"
      },
    .....................
    ................
  });
```

Comment: Please add a comment before negative voting an answer. Here is the jquery documentation regarding it : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/